# Stored procedure returns 2 result data sets - Is there a way to insert only the first data set into a variable but still display the 2nd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a parent stored procedure that runs a series of tests. During the process, the parent creates a "log" record and updates it along the way while setting the test up before it actually executes it.

The test is a stored procedure that returns both a "Y" or "N" depending on the result and a secondary result set with all of the records returned. I'd like the parent stored procedure to grab the "Y" or "N" and stick it into the log table and but also display the secondary result set.

I contemplated putting the update statement within the child stored procedure (the test itself) but then I would need to pass the LogID for every call. Ideally, I would just like to grab the results from the first data set "Y" or "N" and work with that but I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Use an output parameter for the Y/N and a regular SELECT for the detailed results.

Comment: Use an `OUTPUT` parameter?  Personally, if you are really just returning "Y" or "N" then I would use an `OUTPUT` parameter for both results.  I assume you are simply executing the stored procedure and fetching the results into a variable on the calling side at the moment?

Comment: At the moment - the parent stored procedure dynamically builds out the EXEC statement so the result set and structure will change every time in the second dataset. The first dataset will always return a Y or N. The OUTPUT parameter would need to set the variable into the parent stored procedure - would that work still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return the result:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestProcedure
    @ResultSuccessful BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    -- Testing stuff

    IF (/*Test OK*/)
        SET @ResultSuccessful = 1
    ELSE
        SET @ResultSuccessful = 0

    -- Detailed results
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Results

END
```

Call the SP like this:

```
DECLARE @TestOK BIT

-- Will display results from SELECT
EXEC dbo.TestProcedure 
    @ResultSuccessful = @TestOK OUTPUT


IF @TestOK = 1
    -- Do stuff if OK
ELSE
    -- Do stuff if not
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case this isn't clear, here's a quick example of how you can return two results from one stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.dummy (
    @id INT,
    @answer CHAR(1) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --First result
    SELECT @answer = 'Y';

    --Second result
    SELECT @id AS id, 'dog' AS pet;
END;
GO
DECLARE @answer CHAR(1);
EXEC dbo.dummy 1, @answer OUTPUT;
SELECT @answer;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.dummy;
```